# Why are circuits drawn like this(see picture) and not closed?

Tags: circuit-analysis

And how do you analyze them if they have a voltage source in the middle of the circuit? What is the Vin supposed to mean if there is a battery source? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: They mean exactly the same thing that they do without the voltage source.

Comment: Would this be a battery charging diagram?

Comment: they show a diode limiter and a variable diode clipper.

Comment: You couldn't even bother to rotate the image!?

Comment: I actually did not know it was going to post like that. My apologies.

Comment: @Joshyp00: I am pretty sure the vb stands for vbias.  This looks like an exercise to bias this circuit so that there is no distortion from the diodes turn on voltage.

Comment: @jbord39: That makes a lot more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simplification and Vin and Vout are simply references. Basically they're probe points. It's used in order to determine transfer functions of systems. Transfer functions are useful because the resulting equation that you get out of them can give you an idea of how it will impact a signal propagating through them.

A transfer function is H(x) = Vout/Vin. This is useful if you're messing with frequency and AC systems because then you can use frequency transforms to get a system into the frequency domain and then each stage of say a filter can be easily understood. In this way, you can build and understand how a multi-stage filter would act upon a signal/system.

In this case for what I'm assuming is homework or school work, they're just trying to get you used to the format. Basically, with this notation, they'd ask you how does Vout look given Vin where Vin is a variable.

To analyze them, in your head (or on paper) sweep Vin from -infinite to 0 to infinite and determine at what various inputs Vout would transition. For the first case, determine at what points the diodes would turn on and how that would limit the output. In the second case, determine the same thing: when the diodes would turn on and how that impacts the output.

Comment: So, if if the voltage drop across the diodes is assumed to be 0.6V, from Vin=0 to 0.6V, the Vout would read 0? From Vin=0.6V to Vin=infinite, Vout would be equal to Vin-0.6V? Also, if Vin is positive, should the diagram be read from the top Vin node? And if Vin is negative, should it be read from the bottom Vin node?

Comment: @Gabe if you're using 0.6V then if Vin=0 to 0.6V then Vout = Vin because the diode doesn't conduct yet. Above 0.6V the diode conducts and pins the output voltage to 0.6V. The same but reverse would happen on the other diode so from -0.6 to 0V, Vin=Vout, but below -0.6V, it would pin the voltage at -0.6V.

Comment: @Gabe It may be easier to think of a negative voltage as a positive one from the bottom Vin node and a negative one from the top Vin node. Just make sure you do the same flip on the Vout+ and Vout- nodes to get your voltages correct on the output.

Comment: Okay that helps a lot. For the second diagram, would it be correct to say that for Vin=0 to Vin=0.6, Vout=Vin and for Vin=0.6V to infinite, Vout= 0.6V+Vb?

Comment: @Gabe not quite. With the battery in place you now don't have that diode turning on until much higher voltage. Now for that diode to turn on Vin has to be at Vb+0.6. Which means that at any voltage below that the diode simply won't conduct. That means that Vout actually equals Vin until that voltage. So from Vin=0 to Vb+0.6, Vout = Vin. Then after you reach that voltage, Vout becomes pinned to Vb+0.6. You can figure out the negative one (but it'll be very similar).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's an exercise to see the difference between a biased and unbiased circuit.

Without Vb, the circuit will limit any voltages outside the -Vf to Vf range (during this range the voltage will be equal to the input voltage) to either -Vf or Vf.  This limiting occurs once either diode turns on.

Once you add the bias voltages, you shift this clipping range (and if the two Vb are different you can also stretch it out).

Just to clarify, you cannot use superposition to analyze this circuit.  Superposition is only valid for linear systems.  A circuit with a non-linear element (such as BJT or diode) can be "linearized" by biasing, and this is typically done in amplifiers.  Once you bias the circuit and guarantee that the input range does not cause the circuit to become non-linear, then you can apply superposition and the results will be fairly accurate (although still technically wrong).

But in this case, the circuits functionality is completely determined by the nonlinearity of the diodes. So superposition won't work.